# What is the difference between import and fetch(), when using a local .json file in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

To my knowledge and research... Would love correction if my logic is wrong here.

`fetch()` is used when you are trying to get data from a network or cloud service such as AmazonWS, and is "slower?" than importing. (fetch is for data that is constantly updating; weather, stock, etc)

`import` like importing a file `import ProductInformation from './ProductInformation.json';` is used if you have a local file. In react this will load as soon as the component that is using the .json data is rendered.

If I store my .json file inside my components folder which is inside my src folder in create-react-app, I should use import.

In the future if my client wants to use my application and wants to change pricing in the .json file, I should use fetch().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumption is almost correct. Just to clarify.

`fetch or axios` is for raising a http request which ever the server is, aws, azure or even your own static file server where you host your web app. So, if you keep a json file in your `public` folder, as you mentioned about clients' need to make changes, you can use fetch to raise a `GET` to your json file from server.

But if you put the json file in your `src` folder and use import, when you `build` it will be merged with your bundlejs there by the json object will be available inside your application memory but wont be available in the `public` folder.

Comment: saying that, what is a recommended way if you have a static json with kinda 1000 objects. Are there differences between fetch and import in terms of speed?

Answer (score 3):

Those are two completely different things.
`import` is a language construct introduced in the ES2015 version of the language, and as such is specified by the TC39 committee (spec [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports)). On the other hand `fetch` is a web API and as such specified by the WHATWG (spec [here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/))

They do not solve the same problem at all (nor try to aim to). `import` solves the "module problem" where you want to statically declare your dependencies and bind them to JS identifier : this is what `import * as identifier from "module"` is. Fetch however is an API which proposes an interface to access the network in an asynchronous fashion (XMLHTTPRequest used to support synchronous operations iirc). Fetch does it by introducting a new global function, `fetch` and new native classes : `Request`, `Response`, `Headers` and so on...

Where those two things might conceptually overlap is with the future `import()` function which will allow to dynamically load an ES2015 module but is is still in [stage 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import)

Comment: thank you, but can you be more constructive when it comes to a practical issue: say, we have 1000 objects in static json. No need to change, just for searching and filtering content. Do you say that we anyway must use `fetch`? Or 'import' can be an option in this case?

Comment: the difference you should make is between static / compile / build time and runtime. `fetch` is for fetching data at runtime, `import` and `import()` are for fetching code.

Answer (score 2):

Just think of `import` as reading from your filesystem. The `fetch` method should always theoretically be slower than reading from your filesystem, as there's network latency involved.

So yeah, the main difference is where the data is fetched from, as `import` reads from your files and fetch, well, fetches through an HTTP request.

> To get to the more practical answer, just think of it like this :
>
> - if this is a static file, that never changes, just import it, **except if this is private information that you dont want to be included in your final bundle**
> - in all other scenarios, you usually want to fetch it

Comment: about your practical suggestion. What is the proper way to fetch from local storage non-sensitive data. Via local /api call?

Comment: If you're talking about the localStorage API, well there's a browser API for that. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

The way you fetch your data should be depending on where it's stored, the privacy regarding the data you handle is up to the developers to judge and match with the appropriate solution. Hope that makes sense.

Edit: I see your other comment about your 1000 line json file. No matter how big the file is, fetching the file over the network will always have an overhead, making it slower. If you're fetching it server side, it might not matter

Answer (score 1):

simply import is used for import binding which exported by some other module.
but for the fetch api used for manipulating http request and response.

Answer (score 0):

As [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) states, import is used to import bindings which are exported by another module while the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is providing an interface for fetching resources in general. Note that not all Javascript engines support ES6 modules.

The usage of those depends primarily on where the resource is located and what you want to do with it. As you state that you want to change it, my suggestion would be to keep it on the server side and do a `require()` or a `fs.readFile/fs.writeFile` on your json file to provide RESTful functionality.

In your client code you use the `fetch API` with different methods (GET|POST|PUT|...) to initiate changes or to get the information in your json-file.

Answer (score 0):

`import` imports the requested file as a module, but `fetch` is similar to `xhr` calls or HTTP requests to fetch static files over the network.

if you use a bundling tool like webpack, `import`ed modules will be merged into the final bundle (unless you externalized it)

Answer (score -1):

Import will just simply import your file into the current file. While Fetch will return a promise and you can call that file whenever required asynchronously.

Import will get only the exported data from a file. while using fetch you can get full file.

Import get data at compile time while Fetch get data at runtime.