# calling the next javascript via eval, remove the span tag created by the initial JS file

Tags: javascript, html, eval, javascript-injection

I have a html file and 2 JavaScript files: mainscript.js and script1.js. I inject the script1.js inside the mainscript.js. However, what happens is that by calling script1.js, the htmltags created by mainscript.js got removed. Any idea why this happens?

**html code**:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Linear Call</title>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main"><p>hi</p></div>
    <script src="js/recursion_linear/MainScript.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**mainscript.js:**

```
const loadScript = async(url) => {
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const script = await response.text()
    eval(script)
}
var s = document.createElement("span");
document.write("<br>");
s.innerText="This is main script";
s.id="mainscript";
document.body.append(s);


const scriptUrl_1 = "js/recursion_linear/Script1.js"
loadScript(scriptUrl_1)
```

**script1.js**:

```
document.write("<br>");
var s = document.createElement("span");
s.innerText="This is Script1";
s.id="script1";
document.body.append(s);
```

The output is

> This is Script1

While the expected one is

> This is main script
> This is Script1

Comment: Because `document.write()` writes to the document stream, calling `document.write()` on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls `document.open()`, which will clear the document. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Comment: It's also a little strange that you're using `fetch` to get other JS files. You should (almost) never need to use `eval`.  Consider using `import` instead.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50869127/what-is-the-difference-between-import-and-fetch-when-using-a-local-json-file

Comment: Thanks Josh! So the thing is that if I call script1 using these 3 lines:
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = 'js/recursion_linear/Script1.js';
document.head.appendChild(imported);
It works properly. I'm thinking maybe running the script1 using eval causes this issue.

Comment: I would highly discourage using `document.write`. A better approach would be to select an element by ID and then add content using something like `innerText` or `innerHTML`.